# Is this a valid Tic Tac Toe winning condition checker function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a condition checker for a Tic Tac Toe game to announce when the player has won. I have created the function shown below.  However, when I call it and try to apply the winning conditions, nothing happens. I know it's a tedious function but I'm confused on how to make it effective and efficient.

Function:

```
int checker_o(char aray[3][3]){

        if(aray[0][0]=='O'&& aray[0][1]=='O'|| aray[0][2]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 1;
        }

        if(aray[1][0]=='O'&& aray[1][1]=='O' && aray[1][2]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 1;
        }

        if(aray[2][0]=='O'&& aray[2][1]=='O'&& aray[2][2]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 1;
        }

        if(aray[0][0]=='O'&& aray[1][0]=='O' && aray[2][0]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 1;
        }

        if(aray[0][1]=='O'&& aray[1][1]=='O' && aray[2][1]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 1;
        }

        if(aray[0][2]=='O'&& aray[1][2]=='O' && aray[2][2]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 1;
        }

        if(aray[0][0]=='O'&& aray[1][1]=='O' && aray[2][2]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 1;
        }

        if(aray[0][2]=='O'&& aray[1][1]=='O' && aray[2][0]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 1;
        }
}
```

ENTIRE CODE:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>


void map(char a[3][3]){

    int row, column;

    for(row=0;row<3;row++){

        for(column=0;column<3;column++){

            printf ("%c       ", a[row][column]);

        }
        printf("\n \n \n \n \n");
}
}
float getRand() {

    return ((rand() / (RAND_MAX+1.0))*8)+1;
}

int control(int ui, int kb){

    if (kb=='b'){
        ui--;
    }
    if(kb=='c' && 0<ui &&ui<4){
            ui+=5;
    }
    else{

        if(kb=='c' && 3<ui &&ui<7){
                    ui--;
        }
        else{

            if(kb=='c' && 6<ui &&ui<10){
                            ui-=7;
            }
        }
    }
return ui;

}

int checker_o(char aray[3][3]){

        if(aray[0][0]=='O'&& aray[0][1]=='O'&& aray[0][2]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;


        }

        if(aray[1][0]=='O'&& aray[1][1]=='O' && aray[1][2]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }

        if(aray[2][0]=='O'&& aray[2][1]=='O'&& aray[2][2]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;

        }
        if(aray[0][0]=='O'&& aray[1][0]=='O' && aray[2][0]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
        if(aray[0][1]=='O'&& aray[1][1]=='O' && aray[2][1]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
        if(aray[0][2]=='O'&& aray[1][2]=='O' && aray[2][2]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
        if(aray[0][0]=='O'&& aray[1][1]=='O' && aray[2][2]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
        if(aray[0][2]=='O'&& aray[1][1]=='O' && aray[2][0]=='O'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
}
int checker_x(char aray[3][3]){

        if(aray[0][0]=='X'&& aray[0][1]=='X'&& aray[0][2]=='X'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'X' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;

        }

        if(aray[1][0]=='X'&& aray[1][1]=='X' && aray[1][2]=='X'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'X' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;

        }

        if(aray[2][0]=='X'&& aray[2][1]=='X'&& aray[2][2]=='X'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'X' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;


        }
        if(aray[0][0]=='X'&& aray[1][0]=='X' && aray[2][0]=='X'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'X' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;

        }
        if(aray[0][1]=='X'&& aray[1][1]=='X' && aray[2][1]=='X'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'X' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;

        }
        if(aray[0][2]=='X'&& aray[1][2]=='X' && aray[2][2]=='X'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'X' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;

        }
        if(aray[0][0]=='X'&& aray[1][1]=='X' && aray[2][2]=='X'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'X' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;

        }
        if(aray[0][2]=='X'&& aray[1][1]=='X' && aray[2][0]=='X'){
            system("cls");
            printf("Player 'X' Wins!");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
}
int main(){

    int r,c,ui,cntr,cntr2,ran,g,x;
    char kb, aray[3][3]={{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'}};

    srand( time(NULL) );
    getRand();


    map(aray);  
    printf("Which keyboard method would u prefer? \n \n \n");
    printf("(a)\t \t (b)\t \t (c)\n \n easy \t \t mobile \t #Pad \n \n 0 1 2 \t \t 1 2 3 \t \t 7 8 9\n \n");
    printf(" 3 4 5 \t \t 4 5 6 \t \t 4 5 6 \n \n 6 7 8 \t \t 7 8 9 \t \t 1 2 3 \n \n \n");


    scanf("%c", &kb);
    system("cls");
    map(aray);
    do{


        printf("Your Move! \n \n");
        scanf("%i", &ui);
        ui=control(ui,kb);
        r=ui/3;
        c=ui%3;
        if(aray[r][c]=='X'|| aray[r][c]=='O'){
            printf("'X/O' Already exists there \n");
            getchar();
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            aray[r][c]='X';
            system("cls");
            map(aray);
            checker_x(aray);
        }



            ran=getRand();
            g=ran/3;
            x=ran%3;
            if(aray[g][x]=='.'){
                aray[g][x]='O';
                system("cls");
                map(aray);
            }else{
                do{
                    ran=getRand();
                    g=ran/3;
                    x=ran%3;
                    }while (aray[g][x]!='.');
                aray[g][x]='O';
                system("cls");
                map(aray);
        checker_o(aray);
            }

    } while (checker_x(aray)!=1 || checker_o(aray)!=1);

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Might help to remove the same code in each of the if blocks by moving them out into a separate function to make it cleaner and easier to read. the pattern for refactoring should become easier to see the common conditions...

Comment: You can also do it in three `for` loops (check rows, check cols, check diagonals) and compare `array[i][0] == array[i][1] == array[i][2]` and then just `printf("Player \'%c\' Wins!", array[i][0])`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all if statements you need to place statement

```
return 0;
```

Otherwise the function has undefined behaviour.

Also you have a typo inj this statement

```
if (aray[0][0]=='O'&& aray[0][1]=='O'|| aray[0][2]=='O'){
                                     ^^^
```

There must be

```
if (aray[0][0]=='O'&& aray[0][1]=='O'&& aray[0][2]=='O'){
                                     ^^^
```

Take into account that this snippet of code

```
        system("cls");
        printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
        getchar();
        return 1;
```

is duplicated.

You could rewrite the function such a way that this code snippet would be present only one time in the function.

For example

```
const size_t N = 3;
int winner = 0;

for ( size_t i = 0; !winner && i < N; i++ )
{
    size_t j = 0;
    while ( aray[i][j] == 'O' && j < N ) j++;

    winner = j == N;
}
//...

if ( winner )
{
        system("cls");
        printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
        getchar();
}

return winner;
```

You could introduce one more parameter for the character that will be checked. It is better not to use magic numbers and other literals in the program. Give them meaningful names.

Take into account that it is better to use English word `array` instead of `aray`.

Comment: The thing is im doing a coding course at Uni and i havent studied most of what u included above, thank u very much for that clear cut through tho.

Comment: @CcoderBeginner I only included foops. typename specifier size_t you may substitute for int.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written isn't a particularly good way of writing it. The 4 lines

```
system("cls");
printf("Player 'O' Wins!");
getchar();
return 1;
```

are repeated — possibly they should be in a function. You have a long set of tests for `'O'`; you would have an almost identical set of tests for `'X'`, I presume. You should be able to use one function which is passed either `'O'` or `'X'` as an argument and finds whether that has won. You'd also pass that to the reporting function. You can then decide whether the 8 tests can be improved or not; it may not be worth doing so.

You could also use:

```
if ((row1 win) || (row2 win) || … || (top-right to bottom-left win))
{
   report win
}
```

(with the 8 tests in a single `if` statement, each separated from the next by `||`, in which case you might use just the one block of code to report the win. Try to avoid repetition in your code; it is an opportunity for bugs to creep in.

As [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow) also [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33322975/15168), you should return 0 from the function if there is no win.

These changes lead to:

```
int check_winner(char aray[3][3], char x_o)
{
    assert(x_o == 'X' || x_o == 'O');
    if ((aray[0][0] == x_o && aray[0][1] == x_o && aray[0][2] == x_o) ||
        (aray[1][0] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[1][2] == x_o) ||
        (aray[2][0] == x_o && aray[2][1] == x_o && aray[2][2] == x_o) ||
        (aray[0][0] == x_o && aray[1][0] == x_o && aray[2][0] == x_o) ||
        (aray[0][1] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[2][1] == x_o) ||
        (aray[0][2] == x_o && aray[1][2] == x_o && aray[2][2] == x_o) ||
        (aray[0][0] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[2][2] == x_o) ||
        (aray[0][2] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[2][0] == x_o))
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Player '%c' Wins!\n", x_o);
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You might call that with:

```
if (check_winner(board, 'X') || check_winner(board, 'O'))
    break;
```

I think you should consider rewriting the function so it only checks and doesn't report the result:

```
int check_winner(char aray[3][3], char x_o)
{
    assert(x_o == 'X' || x_o == 'O');
    if ((aray[0][0] == x_o && aray[0][1] == x_o && aray[0][2] == x_o) ||
        (aray[1][0] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[1][2] == x_o) ||
        (aray[2][0] == x_o && aray[2][1] == x_o && aray[2][2] == x_o) ||
        (aray[0][0] == x_o && aray[1][0] == x_o && aray[2][0] == x_o) ||
        (aray[0][1] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[2][1] == x_o) ||
        (aray[0][2] == x_o && aray[1][2] == x_o && aray[2][2] == x_o) ||
        (aray[0][0] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[2][2] == x_o) ||
        (aray[0][2] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[2][0] == x_o))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

which could actually be reduced to:

```
int check_winner(char aray[3][3], char x_o)
{
    assert(x_o == 'X' || x_o == 'O');
    return ((aray[0][0] == x_o && aray[0][1] == x_o && aray[0][2] == x_o) ||
            (aray[1][0] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[1][2] == x_o) ||
            (aray[2][0] == x_o && aray[2][1] == x_o && aray[2][2] == x_o) ||
            (aray[0][0] == x_o && aray[1][0] == x_o && aray[2][0] == x_o) ||
            (aray[0][1] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[2][1] == x_o) ||
            (aray[0][2] == x_o && aray[1][2] == x_o && aray[2][2] == x_o) ||
            (aray[0][0] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[2][2] == x_o) ||
            (aray[0][2] == x_o && aray[1][1] == x_o && aray[2][0] == x_o));
}
```

I'm not sure I'd recommend that to you yet.  But then you could use:

```
if (check_winner(board, player))
{
    system("cls");
    printf("Player '%c' Wins!\n", player);
    getchar();
}
```

but you could also use the function to test whether a possible move is a winning move without having the function shout it out before you're ready.

Also, if you're having difficulty debugging, one step is to make sure the board (array) contains what you expect, so have a printing function to show the board, too:

```
static void dump_board(char aray[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            putchar(aray[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

And use that to check that what you've got is correct.  Note, too, how the similarities and differences between the 8 tests are clearly on display.  You can easily spot problems like an `||` where there should be an `&&` because it would stick out like a sore thumb.